# Ballerina can't find JDK

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to run Ballerina on a Linux system but getting the error:

`Error: Ballerina is supported only on JDK 1.8`

But I have the 1.8 JDK and JRE available. I have $CLASSPATH and $JAVA_HOME set appropriately. What do I need to do so Ballerina can find the JDK?

Possibly relevant: this is on shared hosting at Bluehost.

*Update:* In trying to further diagnose the problem, I discovered I was getting out-of-memory errors a lot. Even `java -version` was erroring out. I contacted Bluehost's support, they're taking a look, but I still haven't heard back yet. I'll see if the Ballerina error message goes away once that's fixed.

*Update #2:* Trying a new host. Now I can run Java. Now the error message when trying to run Ballerina is "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly."

I get this when JAVA_HOME is set to:

- The top directory of my JDK
- Same, with a trailing slash
- The /jre directory of my JDK
- Same, with a trailing slash
- The top directory of a separately installed JRE instead

I've gotten Ballerina to work fine on two other computers... just not the one I really need it to. Any new ideas?

Comment: Try to run java -version and javac -version

Comment: Just to double check - is it definitely `1.8`, and not a version *newer* than `1.8`? As Ballerina won't work on 9+.

Comment: Definitely 1.8. jdk1.8.0_221 and jre1.8.0_152 specifically.

Comment: Can you specify which version that you are trying to run? And which pack did you try? I mean the deb, rpm or the zip file?

Comment: I used `ballerina-0.991.0.zip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final fix:

1. Switch to a different hosting service
2. Use the RPM installer rather than the ZIP file

I wish I knew what the RPM installer was doing differently that I missed, but that seems to have done it.

Answer (score 0):

The Ballerina bash script in the zip file requires that the:

```
JAVA_HOME           Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
```

Please ensure that it is set to the java 8 installation location:

```
JAVA_HOME="/path/to/jdk"
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

[1] https://askubuntu.com/a/175547/319090